# How to update a layoutUnit in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces, commandlink

I try to load an include in a "layoutUnit" via "commandLink" but nothing is displayed but if i refreshes the page all is correct.

the commandLink :

```
<p:commandLink update=":center" actionListener="#{sidePviewTest.sideBarAction}" value="Center1">
    <f:param name="pageViewId" value="center1" />
</p:commandLink>
```

the layoutUnit :

```
<p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
    <ui:include src="#{sidePviewTest.includedPage}" />
</p:layoutUnit>
```

I do not understand what the problem is.
Any ideas ?

JSF 2.1
PrimeFaces 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found how to display correctly the content.
I added a panel and I refreshes it instead of the layout.

```
<p:commandLink update=":myPanel" actionListener="#{sidePviewTest.sideBarAction}" value="Center1">
    <f:param name="pageViewId" value="center1" />
</p:commandLink>

<p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
    <p:panel id="myPanel">
    <ui:include src="#{sidePviewTest.includedPage}" />
    </p:panel>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same thing... how if I want to update the header's title?